# Description of closed questions in iOS app lacks links

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, closed-questions, hyperlinks, ios-app

We can now see closed questions in the iOS app which is great, however as you can see here:

> [image]

The words which are links in the sites are not links in the app which shows text only.

Can we have the links in there? Same applies to all types of close reasons, each and its own links.

Comment: Presumably the users who closed should be links too, if we're being consistent

Comment: @mhlester true.

Comment: I'll see what I can do

Comment: Thanks @Arie, appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be implemented in **version 0.1.45**

Comment: Yep, confirmed. Thanks!